# What is the meaning of $\times$ at the begining of an expression?

Tags: notation

I'm reading [a paper](https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AAAI/article/view/5631/5487) with this equation $F_X:(\times_{{U} \in \mathcal U}\mathcal R({U}))$, What does the $\times$ symbol mean at the beginning?[image]

Comment: It's a Cartesian product, probably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know enough about the context to be confident of what $A\times B$ would mean, but I would understand $\times_{U\in\mathcal U}\mathcal R(U)$ to be $\mathcal R(U_1) \times \mathcal R(U_2)\times\cdots$, where $\{U_1,U_2,\ldots\}=\mathcal U$. This is analogous to e.g.  the notation $\bigcup_{x\in X}A_x$.

Then the whole thing means that $F_X$ is a function defined on this $\times$ another similar set, taking values in $\mathcal R(X)$

Comment: Thank you very much @Especially Lime, I update my question with the article, but now I understand it better.